# Google Play Games leaderboard not refreshing

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-games, leaderboard

In profile activity of my game, I load a user's score and rank in a TextView from play games leaderboard and it works fine when the app loads for the first time but after playing the game when the user revisits profile activity the score remains same even though the score in leaderboard updates but the TextViews don't.

Here is my code, for loading score from the leaderboard.

```
 Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).
         loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score),
                 LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful() ) {

                String overAllRank = task.getResult().get().getDisplayRank();
                String overAllScore = task.getResult().get().getDisplayScore();

                mOverAllPoints.setText(overAllScore);
                mOverAllRank.setText(overAllRank);



                Log.i("UserScore", overAllScore + " " + overAllRank);

            }
```

After playing the game I upload user's score using this code

```
 Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score), score);
```

If someone could tell me how to update the score in the TextView that would be very helpful.